# how to make single SQL query for joining, sorting, arranging and set limit?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write a SQL query for joining, sorting, arranging, and setting limits. I have two tables named blogs and blog_categories.

Following is the SQL query-

```
SELECT * 
FROM blogs, blog_categorys 
where blogs.blog_category=blog_categorys.category_id 
ORDER BY blogs.blog_category, blogs.blog_posting_date DESC 
LIMIT 4;
```

In the above query, if I want to see the particular category_id from 1 to 10 category_id's what else do I have to do in this?

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, and the expected output

Comment: Also, if you want to filter the result set, why not use a `WHERE` condition?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!